# OpenGL ES on iOS texture loading - how do i get from a RGBA8888 .png file to a RGB565 texture?

Tags: ios, opengl-es, textures

so i'm working with a bunch of 2048x2048 sprite sheets which fill up memory rather quickly. As is, i'm using the following method (via Ray Wenderlich) to load a texture:

```
- (GLuint)setupTexture:(NSString *)fileName 
{    
    CGImageRef spriteImage = [UIImage imageNamed:fileName].CGImage;
    if (!spriteImage) 
    {
        NSLog(@"Failed to load image %@", fileName);
        exit(1);
    }
    size_t width = CGImageGetWidth(spriteImage);
    size_t height = CGImageGetHeight(spriteImage);
    GLubyte * spriteData = (GLubyte *) calloc(width*height*4, sizeof(GLubyte));
    CGContextRef spriteContext = CGBitmapContextCreate(spriteData, width, height, 8,     width*4,CGImageGetColorSpace(spriteImage), kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast);    
    CGContextDrawImage(spriteContext, CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height), spriteImage);
    CGContextRelease(spriteContext);
    GLuint texName;
    glGenTextures(1, &texName);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texName);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST); 
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, width, height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, spriteData);
    GLenum err = glGetError();
    if (err != GL_NO_ERROR)
        NSLog(@"Error uploading texture. glError: 0x%04X", err);    
    free(spriteData);        
    return texName;    
}
```

so my question is, how do i discard alpha information from the CGImage, then "downsample" the image to fewer bits per pixel, and finally tell OpenGL about it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I use this code to convert the data written by `CGContextDrawImage` to RGB565. It uses optimized NEON code to process 8 pixels at a time on devices with support NEON (every iOS device that runs armv7 code has such a chip). The `data` pointer that you see there is the same as your `spriteData` pointer, I was just too lazy to rename it.

```
void *temp = malloc(width * height * 2);
uint32_t *inPixel32  = (uint32_t *)data;
uint16_t *outPixel16 = (uint16_t *)temp;
uint32_t pixelCount = width * height;

#ifdef __ARM_NEON__
for(uint32_t i=0; i<pixelCount; i+=8, inPixel32+=8, outPixel16+=8)
{
    uint8x8x4_t rgba  = vld4_u8((const uint8_t *)inPixel32);

    uint8x8_t r = vshr_n_u8(rgba.val[0], 3);
    uint8x8_t g = vshr_n_u8(rgba.val[1], 2);
    uint8x8_t b = vshr_n_u8(rgba.val[2], 3);

    uint16x8_t r16 = vmovl_u8(r);
    uint16x8_t g16 = vmovl_u8(g);
    uint16x8_t b16 = vmovl_u8(b);

    r16 = vshlq_n_u16(r16, 11);
    g16 = vshlq_n_u16(g16, 5);

    uint16x8_t rg16 = vorrq_u16(r16, g16);
    uint16x8_t result = vorrq_u16(rg16, b16);

    vst1q_u16(outPixel16, result);
}
#else                
for(uint32_t i=0; i<pixelCount; i++, inPixel32++)
{
    uint32_t r = (((*inPixel32 >> 0)  & 0xFF) >> 3);
    uint32_t g = (((*inPixel32 >> 8)  & 0xFF) >> 2);
    uint32_t b = (((*inPixel32 >> 16) & 0xFF) >> 3);

    *outPixel16++ = (r << 11) | (g << 5) | (b << 0);               
}
#endif

free(data);
data = temp;
```

Comment: `uint8x8_t` type is defined in `arm_neon.h`

Comment: splendid! had to change the glTexImage2D line to the following parameters: `glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, width, height, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT_5_6_5, spriteData);`

Comment: Great answer, you don't see much NEON code out there. To be more hardware-agnostic, have you looked at implementing this using the Accelerate framework?

Comment: @BradLarson Yes, this was my first attempt, but to me the accelerate framework uses even more cryptic names and I had no idea what to look for. I also wanted to target iOS 3.0 and thus I decided to use NEON "directly" since it would also run on iOS 3.x.

Answer (score 3):

Rather than simply changing the colorspace, I might suggest using a PVRTC-compressed texture here.  That should use far less memory on-GPU than even the RGB565 version, because these textures remain compressed rather than expanding into uncompressed bitmaps.

In the "[Best Practices for Working with Texture Data](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/3DDrawing/Conceptual/OpenGLES_ProgrammingGuide/TechniquesForWorkingWithTextureData/TechniquesForWorkingWithTextureData.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008793-CH104-SW1)" section of the OpenGL ES Programming Guide for iOS, Apple says

> Texture compression usually provides the best balance of memory
>   savings and quality. OpenGL ES for iOS supports the PowerVR Texture
>   Compression (PVRTC) format by implementing the
>   GL_IMG_texture_compression_pvrtc extension. There are two levels of
>   PVRTC compression, 4 bits per channel and 2 bits per channel, which
>   offer a 8:1 and 16:1 compression ratio over the uncompressed 32-bit
>   texture format respectively. A compressed PVRTC texture still provides
>   a decent level of quality, particularly at the 4-bit level.

and

> If your application cannot use compressed textures, consider using a
>   lower precision pixel format.

which indicates that you'll get smaller in-memory sizes for the compressed textures than even the ones using a smaller colorspace.

Apple has a good example of this in their [PVRTextureLoader](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/PVRTextureLoader/Introduction/Intro.html) sample application, and I reused some of that code to load PVRTC textures in a [textured cube sample application](http://www.sunsetlakesoftware.com/sites/default/files/CubeExample.zip) I slapped together.  You can look at the "Encode Images" build phase in the PVRTextureLoader for how to script the conversion of PNG textures into PVRTC ones at compile time.

Comment: your answer has encouraged me to look at the PVRTexturLoader example again. I had tried getting it to work with my textures the night before and failed, but i've got it working now. Huge memory footprint improvements! Thanks Mr. Larson

Answer (score 0):

Look at the internalFormat parameter.  Perhaps you could specify GL_R3_G3_B2 to use only 8 bits per pixel or GL_RGB5 may be useful.  There are several options that might be useful.

See [Texture Internal Formats](http://berkelium.com/OpenGL/GDC99/internalformat.html) for more information.